# how to concatenate two variables in round brackets in ajax call

Tags: ajax, concatenation

is there any possible way to concatenate these two variables in ajax call
1.'+result[i].docNo+'
2.'+result[i].pId+'

I am trying so many ways like this --->  '+result[i].docNo+' + '+result[i].petitionId+'
but, notthing works for me. can anyone please give me a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `result[i].docNo + result[i].petitionId`.

When you use `' '`, whatever inside is treated as **String**